# How to create/read/delete a "very hidden" named item (Excel Office JS)

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, excel-web-addins

Is it possible to create, read or delete a hidden named item in the Name Manager in Excel using Excel Office JS?

I am aware that it is possible to create a very hidden sheet, so I am wondering if the same thing is possible with named items.

Comment: You need to provide more details about your scenario, including explaining what you mean by hiding a named item.

Comment: I edited the question. I am referring to the hidden named items in the Name Manager in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

With Office JavaScript API you can programmatically hide and unhide rows by updating the `rowHidden` property on the range object.

```
Excel.run(function (context) {

    // Hide rows 2-5 in 'Sheet1'
    var range = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sheet1").getRange("1:1");
    range.rowHidden = true;

    return context.sync()
        .then(function() {
            console.log("Rows 2-5 have been hidden.");
        });
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

To unhide rows in a range, set the [rowHidden](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.range?view=excel-js-preview#excel-excel-range-rowhidden-member) property to `false`. The property represents if all rows in the current range are hidden. Value is `true` when all rows in a range are hidden. Value is `false` when no rows in the range are hidden. Value is `null` when some rows in a range are hidden and other rows in the same range are not hidden.